# Socket.IO emit inside another socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have made a little chat app working with Socket.IO and I'm trying to emit a message when a user is banned after some spam messages.

I have this working code

```
socket.on('banned-message', function() {
    console.log('ok2');
    io.emit('banned-message');
});
```

I have implemented this code in another working function to send banned messages when a banned user try to send a chat message

```
socket.on('chat-message', function(msg) {
    antiSpam.addSpam(socket);
    io.emit('chat-message', socket.username, socket.picture, msg.msg);

    if (typeof antiSpam.getBans()[0] !== 'undefined' && socket.ip === antiSpam.getBans()[0].ip) {
        console.log('ok');
        socket.on('banned-message', function() {
            console.log('ok2');
            io.emit('banned-message');
        });
    }
});
```

I know it's possible to have a `socket.on` inside another one (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/test/connection.js#L231)
but when the user is banned, my second `socket.on`, inside the `if` is not used, it only return my first console log...

This is the client side code who's called to send a banned message in my chat

```
socket.on('banned-message', function(){
    console.log('bannned send');
    messagesArea.append('<section class="row msgTemplate simpleMessage"><p>banned</p></section>');
    scrollBottom();
});
```

I don't find why this code work fine alone but not in another `socket.on`.

Any ideas, clues to fix this ?

Thank for helping me.

Comment: Does the client-side code send a `banned-message`?

Comment: @MiJyn It only send the mesages inside `messagesArea.append();` on my chat, not in the node server console.

Comment: Sorry, I misworded it. `socket.on('banned-message', ...)` will only run if a `banned-message` is sent to the socket, right? The code you provided for the client-side only listens for a `banned-message` event, it doesn't send it (which would be required for the server code handling that event to run). So I was wondering if another part of your code sends it?

Comment: `socket.on('banned-message', ...) will only run if a banned-message is sent to the socket, right?` I don't think, because when my the code is not in another `socket.on`, it's working well, like I said above. I think the problem is the `socket.on('banned-message', function() {});` is simply not called/used but I don't know why. But no there is not another part of code that send a `banned-message`

Comment: If you keep it inside the function, I think it will keep having a new event handler each time a `chat-message` event is sent and the if clause is true. Is this what you want? How does `banned-message` get called if it's outside the function?

Comment: Each time a `chat-message` event is sent and the if clause is `true` it's only returning to me my console.log and not executing the second event. Each functions `chat-message`, `banned-message` and other are in a global `io.on('connection')` function who's called at every socket connection. So if I use `banned-message` outsite the function, it will be call at every connection, and this is currently working.

Comment: `banned-message` would have to be called a bit later then, since it would take a few milliseconds to register the handler (I would think?)

Comment: I tried but this is not even working